# Debian install: backup partition

Tags: linux, debian, backup, partitioning

I want to re-install my Debian install, for various reasons. Before doing this, I would like to backup my Debian partition, if something goes wrong(highly unlikely). I have backupped entire disks before, but not single partitions.  My partition layout:

sda      8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk

├─sda1   8:1    0    35G  0 part

├─sda2   8:2    0   194G  0 part /

└─sda3   8:3    0     4G  0 part

sda1: Windows 8.1

sda2: Debian Jessie

sda3: swap

Can I just bootup a portable Linux drive using a USB Key, and use "dd" to copy "sda2" to my external hard drive?

And since it is the second partition, do I have to do anything with the MBR, if I wish to restore my backupped partition?

Sorry if these questions sound noobish(or if it's a duplicate), but I researched on how to do it, but wanted to be 100% sure before proceeding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with `dd`. I would probably do it like this:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/media/usb/debian-backup.img
```

where `/media/usb/` is the mount point of your external hard drive.

If you don't resize any of your partitions when doing the reinstall, you won't need to touch the MBR.

Comment: Thank you! This was the final push for me. I tried it yesterday, and it worked fine. Now I'm off to restoring all my data and such.